# Port Forwarding to IP not in LAN

Tags: port-forwarding, static-ip

I am administering a SSH server and trying to configure port forwarding through my router for access outside of the subnet. The server is located at subnet IP address `192.168.86.97` however, when I try to configure the router to port forward to this IP or any IP other than `192.168.0.X`, I get the error

> Internal IP Address is not in LAN.

To solve this, I have tried assigning the device a static IP within the range `192.168.0.X` using:

```
sudo ip address add 192.168.0.97/24 dev eno1
```

However, this IP address assignment does not appear to be reflected on any other machine but the server itself. That is, the server may *ping itself* at `192.168.0.97`, but no other device on the subnet can ping `192.168.0.97`. I want to solve this, and my questions are

1. What does it mean that the Internal IP address `192.168.86.97` is not in LAN?
2. How can I assign this machine an IP address in the range `192.168.0.X` so that the port forwarding works correctly?

I tried changing the router's LAN to `192.168.86.X`, but that just made all of the IP addresses on the network jump to `192.168.87.X`. After doing that, here are the results from these commands

`ip addr show`

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 30:9c:23:df:3a:f9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.97/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global eno1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.87.32/24 brd 192.168.87.255 scope global noprefixroute eno1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::d97d:409f:4793:c98e/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlp26s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 30:24:32:b8:4d:6d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

`ip route show`

```
default via 192.168.87.1 dev eno1 proto dhcp src 192.168.87.32 metric 202
192.168.0.0/24 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.97
192.168.87.0/24 dev eno1 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.87.32 metric 202
```

Comment: What is this "router"?

Comment: It's a Netgear C3000-100NAS  router.

Comment: Setting aside for the moment that it's home networking equipment, the message means what it says: It won't port forward to an address not in its subnet. You'll probably have to forward it to your other router and port forward it again from there. Or, of course, replace the equipment with something more appropriate for business use.

Comment: @JonDeaton Could you please update the question with the output of `ip addr show` and `ip route show` for a better understanding?

Comment: @ManuelFlorian okay, I updated the question with those results!

Comment: @JonDeaton Let me see if I get it right. ArchLinux `192.168.87.32` is wired connected to a Netgear `192.168.87.1` and you want to reach `192.168.0.X/24` network from your ArchLinux?

Comment: Yes, they are connected as you describe. I want to port-forward through Netgear to `192.168.87.X`, but it only allows port-forwarding to `192.168.86.x`

Comment: I see you just changed the ip address and now the Netgear will only allow to forward to that particular network, in this case `192.168.86.X` because is the only network it recognizes or it's attached to.

Comment: @ManuelFlorian yes exactly. However, now I can't get the ArchLinux to have a static IP address in the range `192.168.86.X`

Comment: Why not? What have tried?

Comment: I have tried assigning it static ip addresses in the range `192.168.86.X`. I use `sudo ip address add 192.168.86.7/24 dev eno1` but I can't ping that IP address from any other machine on the network. Nor, does the port forwarding work after I do that. I have also tried assigning a static IP by editing `/etc/netctl/eno1`.

Comment: I'm not a user of Arch Linux so try [this](https://www.ostechnix.com/configure-static-dynamic-ip-address-arch-linux/).

Comment: That was one of the first things that I tried.

Comment: Any errors while setting up your IP?

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is another device between your router and server.

It turned out that there was a wireless signal extender between the router and server. The router was assigning IP addresses in the range `192.168.0.X`, but the signal extender was assigning IPs in the range `192.168.86.X`. Thats why device IPs weren't getting assigned into the router's LAN.

To solve the problem in it's entirety, I just configured the router to forward a port to the signal extender, then configure the signal extender to forward that port *again* to the server.